# Obtaining scans from HP LaserJet CM2320mf via email

Tags: smtp, hp, windows-server-2012, printer

I am trying, since I purchased the laser printer, to use the scan to email functionality, so far to no success and no lack of trying.

The printer does not support sending emails via authentication. HP requires that it sends out emails via unauthenticated SMTP. My email domain requires authenticated SMTP. I even agree with that, not that I have a choice in the matter.

Since I have a Windows Server attached to my local two computer network, I tried to install a local SMTP Server (Argosoft's MailServer.Net. I created a fake mail domain and set that no authentication is needed. I worked with the CEO of the company, as much as he allowed, and got to the point, where I got the mails from the laser printer bounced back.

The reason given was that I am trying to send mail from a domain that does not allow unauthenticated emails. Basically, my main IP address outside the firewall is a dynamically assigned IP address, not a static one, and one not assigned for a mail server.

Since I am not about to purchase a static mail server IP, just for the laser printer, is there anything that I can do that can resolve the issue?

I have no clue what HP thought, when they added this feature.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

My local workstation is Windows 8 Pro, but that does not make a difference, IMHO. The server is Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 5):

Having a printer/scanner with a non-authenticating SMTP client is quite usual. The equally usual approach to this is to set up mail server as a relay, which accepts unauthenticated mail from the local network and forwards it to another mail server, if necessary with authentication. Using a "fake domain" is not a good approach for this.

If and how this ArgoSoft stuff supports a relay only setup you need to look up in the doc, but every Unix style SMTP server easily does this.

Comment: I did not purchase Argosoft's software yet. I am currently just evaluating the software. The company answered some questions, but basically blew off the problem. I am open to a solution. I will investigate setting up a relay on the Windows server. If Unix has software, then Microsoft Windows Server should as well.

Comment: Windows Server 2012 has a built in SMTP virtual server that is part of IIS.  You can add it via Server Manager -> server roles -> SMTP server.  You admin it via IIS and you should be ablet o configure it to accept mail and act as a mail relay for your printer.